# How many times has Apocalypse transferred his powers into another mutant's body?

Tags: marvel, x-men, x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-apocalypse

In X:Men Apocalypse we are shown Apocalypse transferring not only his consciousness, but his powers into another mutant's body:

Without any reference to the comics, how many times has he done this? How many other mutant powers has he gathered over the time of his life before he was trapped in the collapsed pyramid.

#### I am looking for *in* or *out* of universe answers, preferably related to the the movies. If there is no current concrete answer to this, any information pertaining to Apocalypse's power and how he got it will be accepted.

Comment: Kylo, there's Marvel Cinematic, which is the Disney/Marvel one with Avengers, and then X-Men Cinematic which is the Fox one with X-Men and I guess Deadpool (it's a mess). It's alright if you're not sure, community edits are for this purpose.